# Wordpress the_excerpt showing same data for all id's

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a cart plugin for Wordpress. It uses the_excerpt to show the product description. it works on all pages except the checkout page. On the checkout page it shows the same description for all the products. The description it shows is always from the first product in the database even if that product is not in the cart. I have tried many variations nothing fixes it. it pulls the correct id and price for the product but just the description is always the same for al products.

```
 <?php the_excerpt(get_the_ID()); ?>
       <input id="item-<?php echo $item->ID; ?>-price" name="item-<?php echo $item->ID; ?>-price" type="hidden" value="<?php echo intval($price); ?>"/>
```

In the code above, the price pulls correctly but the_excerpt is same for every product.

i have tried:

```
    <?php the_excerpt(get_the_ID()); ?>
    <?php the_excerpt($item->ID); ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(get_the_excerpt); ?>
```

i have also tried if and while but then it just shows all 20 product descriptions for each product

this is all the code for the page:

```
     <script>
window.onload = calculate_order(0,0);

function calculate_order(qty_item, qty_type) {
    //qty_type could be add or substract
    total = 0;
    numberofitems = 0;
    if (qty_type == "add"){
        document.getElementById((qty_item+"-qty")).value++;
    }
    if (qty_type == "subtract") {
        if (document.getElementById((qty_item+"-qty")).value > 0) {
           document.getElementById((qty_item+"-qty")).value--;
        }
    }
    //return;
    $('.store-item').each(function(i, obj) {
        price = document.getElementById(($(this).attr("id")+"-price")).value;
        //price = price * 1 ;
        qty = document.getElementById(($(this).attr("id")+"-qty")).value;
        //qty = qty * 1;
        numberofitems = numberofitems + (qty*1);
        total         = total + ((price*1)*(qty*1));
        //alert (numberofitems);
    });
    document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML = total ;
    document.getElementById("total_qty").value = numberofitems ;
    discount = 100*Math.floor(numberofitems/2);
    document.getElementById("total_discount").innerHTML = discount ;
    document.getElementById("final_price").innerHTML = (total - discount);
    document.getElementById("tot_discount").value = discount ;
    document.getElementById("tot_order").value = (total - discount);
    document.getElementById("tot_price").value = total ;
    if (numberofitems <2) {
        $("#total-price").hide();
        $("#total-discount").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#total-price").show();
        $("#total-discount").show();
    }
    return;
  }
 </script>
 <div id="shopping-cart">


  <div>
  <h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="section group">
 <div class="col span_1_of_4"> Items in Cart</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_4">
  Description
</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_4" style="text-align:center">
 Price
</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_4" style="text-align:right">
  Quantity
</div>

</div></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<div class="cart-header">
   <div id="checkout-form" class="cart-header" style="border:0px;">
        <fieldset class="addressdetails">
            <table width="330" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr><td style="width:120px;padding-bottom:5px">Your Name:</td><td style="padding-bottom:5px"><input id="yName" type="text" name="order_name2" style="background-color:#D3E3F8"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Your Email</td><td style="padding-bottom:5px"><input id="Email" type="text" name="order_email" style="background-color:#D3E3F8"/> </td></tr>
            <tr><td></br></td><td>
            <tr><td style="width:120px;padding-bottom:5px">Shipping Name:</td><td style="padding-bottom:5px"><input id="Name" type="text" name="order_name" style="background-color:#D3E3F8"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Shipping Address:</td><td style="padding-bottom:5px"><input id="Address" type="text" name="order_address" style="background-color:#D3E3F8"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>City: </td><td style="padding-bottom:5px"><input id="City" type="text" name="order_city" style="background-color:#D3E3F8"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>State:</td><td style="padding-bottom:5px"><input id="State" type="text" name="order_state" style="background-color:#D3E3F8"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Zip Code:</td><td style="padding-bottom:5px"><input id="ZipCode" type="text" name="order_zipcode" style="background-color:#D3E3F8"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Country:</td><td><input id="Country" type="text" name="order_country" style="background-color:#D3E3F8"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td></br></td><td>

            <tr><td>Comments</td><td style="padding-bottom:5px"><textarea id="Comments" name="order_comments" style="width:180px;background-color:#D3E3F8"></textarea></td></tr>
            </table>


            </br>
        </fieldset>
        </br>
        <div><label></label><center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Order" class="submit_order_button"/></center></div>
</div>
</div>

<?php $total = 0; ?>
<?php $nitems = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($_POST as $item => $quantity): ?>
<?php $matches = array(); ?>
<?php if (preg_match('/^item-([0-9]+)$/', $item, $matches) === 1 and intval($quantity) > 0): ?>
<?php $item = get_post(intval($matches[1])); ?>
<?php if ($item): ?>
  <?php $nitems++; ?>
  <?php $price = intval(get_post_meta($item->ID, 'price', true)); ?>
  <?php $total += $price; ?>


   <div class="section group" style="margin:10px 0 10px 0">
   <input id="item-<?php echo $item->ID; ?>-ID" type="hidden" name="art_id[]]" value="<?php echo $item->ID; ?>"/>

   <div class="col span_1_of_4" style="text-align:center">
      <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($item->ID, 'checkout-thumbnail'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_4">
      <h2><?php
        $title = explode('(', $item->post_title, 2);
        echo $title[0];
        if (count($title) > 1) {
          echo '<span class="parenthetical">(';
          echo preg_replace('/ /', '&nbsp;', $title[1]);
          echo '</span>';
        }
      ?></h2>
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php
$my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
if ( $my_excerpt != '' ) {
// Some string manipulation performed
}
echo get_the_excerpt($item->ID); // Outputs the processed value to the page
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>         

  </div>
   <div class="col span_1_of_4" style="text-align:center">
 $ <span id="price"><?php echo $price; ?></span>
</div>

       <input id="item-<?php echo $item->ID; ?>-price" name="item-<?php echo $item->ID; ?>-price" type="hidden" value="<?php echo intval($price); ?>"/>

    <div class="col span_1_of_4" style="text-align:right">
      <input type="text" class="store-item-quantity" style="width:20px" name="item-<?php echo $item->ID; ?>-qty" id="item-<?php echo $item->ID; ?>-qty" value="<?php echo intval($quantity); ?>" readonly />
        <input type='button' class="qtybutton" name='add' onclick='javascript: calculate_order("item-<?php echo $item->ID; ?>", "add");' value='+'/>
        <input type='button' class="qtybutton" name='subtract' onclick='javascript: calculate_order("item-<?php echo $item->ID; ?>", "subtract");' value='-'/>
    </div></div>
    <!--<input id="item-<?php echo $item->ID; ?>-qty" type="text" value="<?php echo intval($quantity); ?>"/>-->
  </div></div>






<?php endif; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>


 <!-- MSR 11062013 display mode of discount -->
 <?php $discount = 100*intval(floor($nitems/2)); ?>
 <div id="price-totals" style="padding-right:20px">
  Price includes international shipping<br />
 <table id="price-table">
  <input id="total_qty" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $nitems; ?>"/>
  <tr id="total-price" <?php if ($nitems < 2) echo 'style="display:none"' ?>>
    <td class="price-label">Total:</td>
    <td class="price-value">$ <span id="total_price"><?php echo $total; ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="total-discount" <?php if ($nitems < 2) echo 'style="display:none"' ?>>
    <td class="price-label">Discount:</td>
    <td class="price-value">$ <span id="total_discount"><?php echo $discount; ?></span>    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="price-label"><strong>Final Price:</strong></td>
    <td class="price-value"><strong>$ <span id="final_price"><?php echo $total - $discount; ?></strong></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="tot_price" type="hidden" name="tot_price" value="<?php echo $total; ?>"/>
<input id="tot_discount" type="hidden" name="tot_discount" value="<?php echo $discount; ?>"/>
<input id="tot_order" type="hidden" name="tot_order" value="<?php echo $total - $discount; ?>"/>
  </div>
 </div>

 </div>


 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass parameters to `the_excerpt`, it always uses the "post in the loop", same goes for `get_the_excerpt` (I was wrong earlier). By looking at your code, you are looping over each item and getting its corresponding `WP_Post` object. Its excerpt should then be in `$item->post_excerpt`

A potentially cleaner way of doing this would be to create a new WP_Query that you can loop over. See http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops

Comment: that did not work. also i have tried with "loop" but then it just shows every description for each product i.e i have 20 products and each product in the cart shows all 20 descriptions.

Comment: Then you need to show more code. How are you looping over your items? Are you getting the ID with `$item->ID`? What cart plugin are you using? Are products some kind of Wordpress post type or some other object?

Comment: I have added the code for the whole page. the only issue is the the_excerpt.

Comment: @russ I was wrong before; please see my updated answer.